# PHP Warning: ftp_login(): Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, ftp

I can't loggon to linux server when I'm trying to get some files from home directory..

```
<?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "xxxx";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'xxx', 'xxx');

var_dump($login);
// then do something...

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn); 
?>
```

what i supposed to do !?? I'm getting this error :

> Warning: ftp_login(): Permission denied

Comment: obviously its your access problem, ask admin to allow access to the user from whom you are are trying to connect , **Permission denied** means your connection request is refused because you don't have access.

Comment: It's an authentication issue. Ensure that you're using the right credentials.

Comment: Did you try the same credentials in a standalone FTP client?

Comment: yes i did with winscp and it work

Comment: how can i allow access to users to read and write in linux server ?